# How to Reset Sharepoint 2010 Web Analytics reports

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, central-administration, web-analytics

I have been testing Sharepoint Foundation 2010 web application, now its time to move site to Live. Customer is asking to reset the web analytics counter to 0.
I tried stopping web analytics data processing service and Web Analytics Web service. They both stopped sucessfully and started sucessfully, but data still exists in site collection.

Any ideas on how to complete this task.

Thank You

Comment: Reprovisioned Service Didint Worked.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply find the table that contains the data, then truncate the table used to store analytics.

Comment: Where can i find the Database table fo the web analytics